# Intermittingly loosing messages when using transactional outbox

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit transactional outbox pattern. Today, we faced some issues I have found that some messages are not delivered to consumer.

The issue is that we have 3 apps and all are using same DB and calling `UseBusOutbox` method which will add `BusOutboxDeliveryService` hosted service. I have some feeling that because of these app using the same outbox tables that's why the messages are pushed (saved in DB) but not delivered to consumers?

How to avoid this?

Comment: If you're having issues using MassTransit, I'd recommend [Commercial Support](https://masstransit.io/support).

Answer (score 0):

In our case there was local broker and remote broker. Someone connected to remote DB and local broker which consume message from remote DB but sends to local broker.